# How to get difference of months from Dates in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, date, time

I have one date in format of `date = "2022-07-03 10:09:19"`
Need to get difference of months from Today date and time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your effort? Have you tried to use `java.time` package?

Comment: I tried to parse this to multiple way
used simpleformat, DateTimeFormatter in multiple ways

Comment: Please add some of your code (which didn't work) to your question. No problem if it does not work…

Comment: 10 AM on that date in what time zone? As currently written, your question is impossible to answer accurately. Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: @AminMal Without a time zone, that approach is inaccurate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here and when you post a question, tell us what your search brought up and specify how it fell short of solving your problem. It’s for your own sake since (1) you often find a better answer faster that way (2) it allows us to give preciser and more focused answers. It also tends to prevent or at least reduce the number of downvotes. And your question is on the brink of being closed. Maybe you can’t find a full answer to your question in one place, but you can certainly find all the pieces.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage `java.time` library. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val dateOld = "2022-07-03 10:09:19".replace(" ", "T")
val dateNew = "2022-11-03 10:09:19".replace(" ", "T")

val l1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateOld)
val l2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateNew)

val months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(l1, l2)
```

For calculating from current time you can use:

```
val date = "2021-07-03 10:09:19".replace(" ", "T")

val l1 = LocalDateTime.parse(date)
val l3 = LocalDateTime.now()

val months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(l1, l3)
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: +1 for `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between`, but I would use a `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `String` manipulation here. However, this will obviously work ;-)

Comment: Nice suggestion, let me update the answer. I was too lazy to find out the exact ISO for the input format.

Comment: There is no ISO for this input format, I think… We will have to provide a matching pattern for it.

Comment: Yep, saw your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MONTHS) to solve it

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime previousDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

long diffMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(now, previousDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use `java.time` if possible

You can parse the datetime `String`, add a time zone and take the current day or moment in the same time zone. Then you can extract the date and calculate the `Period.between` those two.

Here's an example in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String someTime = "2022-07-03 10:09:19";
    // prepare a formatter that can parse such a String
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    // prepare the time zone 
    // (I will use UTC, but the zone depends on the one of the input)
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    // parse the String, apply the zone and directly extract the date
    LocalDate then = LocalDateTime.parse(someTime, dtf)
                                  .atZone(utc)
                                  .toLocalDate();
    // get the date of today in the zone
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(utc);
    // calculate the period between the two dates
    long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(then, today);
    // prepare some meaningful message to be printed
    String msg = String.format(
            "The difference in months between %s (then) and %s (today) is %d months",
            then, today, months);
    // and actually print it
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Output:

```
The difference in months between 2022-07-03 (then) and 2022-08-03 (today) is 1 months
```

Comment: Nice and full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the given date to an instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime`, then you can get an instance of `java.time.Period` for the two dates, and from that, you can get the months.

In Java:

```java
final DateTimeFormatter parser = … // An appropriate parser for the given format
final var otherDate = LocalDateTime.parse( dateString, parser );
final var deltaPeriod = Period.between( LocalDateTime.now(), otherDate );
final var result = deltaPeriod.getYears() * 12 + deltaPeriod.getMonths(); // or use Period::toTotalMonths()
```